# Sound to signal and signal to actions?

Tags: c#, java, api, audio, signals

Hi i have some problems with my project. 
My project specification is to change the sound to signal and change the signal to sound.
I need some api to change this, i think.
i can't find api that can change sound to signal.

Project Details

When i sing happy song, the ball in my computer move so fast.
When i sing sad song, the ball in my computer move slow.I think i need to check with 
signal frequency. But i don't have no idea about that. PLZ help to solve that problem thanks

Comment: interesting, there's a Beat Finder plugin in Audacity, http://code.google.com/p/audacity/source/browse/audacity-src/trunk/plug-ins/beat.ny, not good, but maybe you can have a look